# UDP echo server with one thread per client

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, echo

I had a simple TCP echo server with one thread per client (it works), so i tried to transform it into UDP but faced problem after running server:

> "pthread_create() resource temporarily unavailable"

. Here is my server code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 1027
#define BACKLOG 5
#define MAXLINE 256

#define SA struct sockaddr

typedef struct serve_clientArg {
    int socket;
    SA *addr;
    socklen_t addrlen;
} SCARGS;

void Pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, pthread_attr_t *attr,
void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *arg)
{
    int rc;

    rc = pthread_create(thread, attr, start_routine, arg);
    if(rc) {
        errno = rc;
        error("pthread_create()");
    }
}
```

**reads()** and **writen()** are using **recvfrom()** and **sendto()** functions

```
void *serve_client(void* arg)
{
    char s[MAXLINE];
    ssize_t rc;
    SCARGS *args = Malloc(sizeof (SCARGS));
    args = (SCARGS*) arg;
    int socket = args->socket;
    SA *addr = args->addr;
    socklen_t addrlen = args->addrlen;
    free(arg);

    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    while((rc = reads(socket, s, MAXLINE, addr, &addrlen)) > 0) {
        writen(socket, s, rc, addr, addrlen);
    }
    Close(socket);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int socket;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
    SCARGS *arg;
    pthread_t thread;

    socket = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    Bind(socket, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    for(;;) {
        arg = Malloc(sizeof (SCARGS));
        arg->socket = socket;
        arg->addr = (SA*) &cliaddr;
        arg->addrlen = sizeof (cliaddr);

        Pthread_create(&thread, NULL, serve_client, (void*) arg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I also had a TCP client and after transformation into UDP it works. I think i have done a stupid mistake, but i cant find it... Please help me find mistakes!

Comment: Your program keeps creating threads until it can't - what were you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(;;) {
    arg = Malloc(sizeof (SCARGS));
    arg->socket = socket;
    arg->addr = (SA*) &cliaddr;
    arg->addrlen = sizeof (cliaddr);

    Pthread_create(&thread, NULL, serve_client, (void*) arg);
}
```

You allocate memory and create new threads inside an endless loop with no kind of blocking (as you might have done in TCP with `accept`). Therefore it quickly runs out of resources:

> "pthread_create() resource temporarily unavailable"

Apart from that you use the same socket in all threads. But when you have only a single socket it does not really make sense to have multiple threads handling it. I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve with this design.